# Stylus pen input not working on Unity android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, stylus-pen

I have a problem that I cannot input using the Stylus pen in Unity Android.

When the Stylus pen touches the screen, the first OnPressDown event is called, but then OnPressUp is not called, and all pen inputs are not operated afterwards.
OnClick of Unity's UGUI Button is not being called either.

Pens that work normally in other Android apps, but the above problem occurs in Android apps built by Unity.

The pen is made in China, but the exact model is unknown.

Is there anything in doubt?

Please understand that the sentence may be awkward using a translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself

The handling of pen input is included in the Input System Package supported in Unity 2019 or higher, so the problem was solved by installing the package.